# Для чего нужна "земля" (ground) на разных board`ах?

Tags: arduino

Для чего нужна "земля" (ground) на разных board`ах (Arduino...)? Это же не заземление)

Comment: Отдельно есть корпус, отдельно есть минус источника питания. Иногда (не всегда) они соединяются.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F_(%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: "Земля" - нулевая точка, от которой отсчитывается потенциал напряжений (в "плюс" или в "минус", зависит от схемы). Заземление и земля - разные вещи.